# Comparing data of two row in single dataframe

Tags: python

```
MasterAgreementId   MasterAgreementType Data Source Break Type
11000002    ISDA    Source System   
11000002    ISDA    CMRS    
11000043    ISDA    CMRS    
11000049    ISDA    Source System   
11000049    ISDA    CMRS    
1451057679  ISDA    Source System
```

I have a dataframe containing data like this. I want to use MasterAgreementId as key for comparison and want output like:

```
MasterAgreementId   MasterAgreementType Data Source Break Type
11000002    ISDA    Source System   Identical
11000002    ISDA    CMRS    Identical
11000043    ISDA    CMRS    Difference
11000049    ISDA    Source System   Identical
11000049    ISDA    CMRS    Identical
1451057679  ISDA    Source System   Difference
```

I want to achieve this without iteration.

Comment: do you want to compared it with itself? how do you arrive at `Identical` and `Difference`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using Pandas? Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Answer (score 0):

by using the MasterAgreementid,

i used duplicated to populate another column which is giving me false and true values against each of the rows and now i am trying to calculate the identical and difference against them

Comment: Per @jpp comment, please read the MCVE, and this isn&#39;t an answer, rather a comment. You&#39;ll also want to take a look at np.which or shift ().

Comment: code which worked for solving the problem statement                                                         
df['Matching Key'] = df.duplicated(['MasterAgreementId'], keep=False)
df.loc[df_Source_FileName['Matching Key'] == True , 'Break Type'] = 'Identical'

Comment: The earlier issue was resolved, now i want to add in the earlier issue,